# index on rowentrytimestamp

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have a query with two tables joined together with inner join having a 'where condition' performing the operation of fetching the records for previous one month.
one of the tables has its field 'rowentrytimestamp' which is the timestamp when the row is entered for the record.

Example Query:

```
Select table1.a, table1.b, table2.c, table2.d, table2.e, table1.f,table1.g
from table1 inner join
     table2
     on table1.a = table2.a
where table2.c in (x, y, z) and table2.rowentrytimestamp >= DateAdd(mm,-1,getDate())
```

in order to have faster execution is it a good choice to add index on rowentrytimestamp. Would there be anything which I should consider when adding the index for timestamp.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an index on `table2(b, rowentrytimestamp, a, c)`, then the index will cover the query.  Whether `b` or `rowentrytimestamp` should go first depends on which is the more selective.

So, adding `rowentrytimestamp` to an index *might* make sense as part of a larger index.  It might have some effect on its own.  But with two inequalities in the `where` clause, the use of indexes is somewhat limited.

Comment: the query fetches more columns from table2, which I have edited now, so would an index on table2(c, rowentrytimestamp, a) makes sense?.  
To add there is already an index on column a for table2 which is been used